# Firebase 'no such instance field' error

Tags: java, android, firebase

I had some code that got data from Firebase, which worked, but stopped working somehow. Everything in the `ValueEventListener` is skipped, due to an error it gives me: 'No such instance field: 'mDatabase'. How can I fix this? I have tried restarting Android Studio and my pc, but it keeps giving me this error...

Code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ValueEventListener dataListener = new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          // Make list for ReisData objects
          reisDataList = new ArrayList<ReisData>();

          // Put objects from database into java object list
          for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("allData").getChildren()) {
               data = ds.getValue(ReisData.class);
               reisDataList.add(data);
          }

     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         // Getting data failed, log a message
         Log.w("Error:", databaseError.toException());
     }
 };
 mDatabase.addValueEventListener(dataListener);
```

**EDIT:** I think I may have found the problem. Under this code I added some code to display the contents of `reisDataList`, which seems to interfere with the `ValueEventListener`. Is there a way I can run this code without getting any errors?

Added code:

```
    MyTripsAdapter myTripsAdapter = new MyTripsAdapter(getContext(), reisDataList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mijnReizenList);
    listView.setAdapter(myTripsAdapter);*/
```

Comment: So your code is not compiling?

Comment: Well, the code runs, but it skips over the contents of the ValueEventListener.

Comment: Do one thing for confirmation, put breakpoint in debug mode inside of onDataChange and change your database directly from firebase website.

Comment: Just tried that, same result, it doesn't get to the breakpoint.

Comment: Could you make sure you are referring to a correct end point. Please print or debug reference of database in your code and match it with targetting reference

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to this, what do you mean I should do exactly?

Comment: I mean check value of this by placing debugger. mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Comment: mDatabase contains the link to my Firebase database. However, when I set a breakpoint on the ValueEventListener, it seems to have forgotten the value for mDatabase.

Comment: I think I found the problem, but I'd like to run this last piece of code after the ValueEventListener (see Edit in post), is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you to solve the problem.

public class Map_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference databaseRefer;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
private ArrayList<Location> reisDataList = new ArrayList<>();
private MyTripsAdapter myTripsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); //getting instance of FireDatabase

    //getting db reference from specific node, here you're not refering the node
    databaseRefer = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("windfirm/future");  

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mijnReizenList);

    databaseRefer.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        // pendingCount is the count for dataSnapshot children
        long[] pendingCount = { dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() };

       //parsing all the node list data from dataSnapshot
         for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


               String rightLocation = child.child("lat").getValue().toString();
               String leftLocation = child.child("lon").getValue().toString();
               String city = child.child("city").getValue().toString();
               reisDataList.add(new  Location(rightLocation, leftLocation, city)); //adding object to arraylist

            // we loaded a child, check if we're done
               pendingCount[0] = pendingCount[0] - 1;
               if (pendingCount[0] == 0) {
                   myTripsAdapter = new MyTripsAdapter(getContext(), reisDataList);
                  listView.setAdapter(myTripsAdapter);
               }               


           }


       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });


  }
```

}

Comment: I tried to use your code, but the adapter doesn't get notified in some way. The adapter is set, which leads to a null pointer exception: the data from the ValueEventListener has not been returned yet. Is there any other way I can tell the adapter to wait until data is given back from the ValueEventListener?